# Solutions to Diophantine equation for Ramanujan graph construction

Tags: graph-theory, diophantine-equations, ramanujan

I am working with so-called Ramanujan graphs which have the property that a lower bound on their girth can be stated. I am reading about those in paper [On the Construction of Turbo Code Interleavers Based on Graphs with Large Girth](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=997082) where such graphs are used in order to construct good Turbo code interleavers.

While going through the construction of those graphs, they speak about having to solve the diophantine equation

$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=p \quad(in\quad \mathbb{Z})$

where $p$ is an odd prime and $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Z}$ are integers that fullfil

- if $p\equiv1\mod{4}$ then $a>0$ odd and $b,c,d$ are even.
- if $p\equiv 3 \mod{4}$ then $a>0$ odd; $b,c$ odd and $d$ even

It is stated that such a diophantine equation has several answers and so by using them you can construct the associated Ramanujan graph. However, as I am not an expert in diophantine equations I do not know if such an equation has to have solutions under such assumptions, and if it has, how many solutions should it have. Consequently, I am interested in knowing when does such diophantine equation have solutions, and how can I know (if possible) how many possible answers to such are possible under the conditions given by $p$.

Comment: The conditions (apart from $a>0$) are automatically satisfied up to permutation. The total number (Lagrange Jacobi) is $8(p+1)$, so since one of $a$ $b$ $c$ $d$ is specified, divide by $4$, and since you ask $a>0$, divide again by $2$, so in every case the answer is that there are $p+1$ solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I had the intuition that there are $p+1$ solutions to the equation. One last thing, what do you mean by Lagrange-Jacobi in the parenthesis?

Comment: Lagrange showed that any $n$ is a sum of 4 squares, and if I am not mistaken, Jacobi showed that the number of such representations is $8(\sigma_1(n)-\sigma_1(n/4))$.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand what you were saying there.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a little bit more about this question in the following famous paper: "Ramanujan Graphs" by Lubotzky, Phillips and Sarnak, Combinatorica,8(3), 261-277, 1988. The discussion is on the second page of the paper.